# Which C# library allows reliable SVG to PDF conversion?

Tags: .net, pdf, svg, pdf-generation

I'm looking for a (not necessarily free) .Net library which is:

- Maintained
- Reliable
- Production ready

I can't use a rasterized image format because I don't want to lose the benefit of having a graphic vector on the output media.

I'm currently using Aspose.Pdf's as the general answer to PDF-related questions, and I would like to change because:

- The API changes without backward compatibility too often.
- There are way too many bugs that are painful to work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research, it appears that such a library doesn't exist yet or is hard to find. I'll have to stick with Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) on the command line? It's free, works on all major operating systems, and can be called trivially using library system calls.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10400963/472495), but use the `--export-pdf` option instead of `--export-png`. I've used it myself on a server application, and it is very good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't feel comfortable with executing external processes involving unmanaged code on the production platform. That would not be accepted by the IT anyways.

Comment: @SamuelRossille: I'm not au fait with the phrase 'unmanaged code' (not a .net person) but think it's got something to do with permissions. If that's the case, consider using a separate VPS with a queue of jobs - which will keep your .net application isolated from any vulns in your converter application.

Comment: This is a typical .NET response. Managed code refers to those things that run within the memory space of the .NET managed memory space. When you pinvoke an external command line operation, you have no control over how that runs. This response is common in languages like C# on Windows, where it is quite difficult to invoke the command shell, as opposed to languages like Ruby or Python on Linux, where it is incredibly easy and common to work on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a direct API, but it would be easy to generate SVG to bitmap with [something like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910/converting-svg-to-png-using-c-sharp). And stuff the add the image to a PDF with many libraries that [write PDF like ITextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I forgot to mention that I want to preserve the advantage of a vector graphics in the output. I Edited the question