# Image cropped while converting from SVG to PNG using ImageMagick

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a SVG file similar to

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c1/latin_capital_letter_a_with_acute.svg

When I use ImageMagick to convert it to a PNG like this:

```
convert latin_capital_letter_a_with_acute.svg tmp.png
```

then only the top portion of the character is visible.

The SVG file doesn't specify any height and width. If I manually specify width="25cm" height="25cm" in the XML file then the full character in a corner as small image with a large background filling the rest of the image. I have searched in Stackexchange and various forums but couldn't find a solution for this.

I have tried the following using PHP as well. But it is still producing the cropped image.

- [how to resize an SVG with Imagick/ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383305/how-to-resize-an-svg-with-imagick-imagemagick)

I think this is an issue with detecting the correct size of the SVG image. But can't think of an easy way to do this.

Comment: Try giving the SVG a viewBox attribute on the root `<svg>` element.

Comment: Which is your version of ImageMagick? What is the output of `convert -version`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I converted the SVG from your link sucessfully using this command:

```
convert    \
 http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c1/latin_capital_letter_a_with_acute.svg \
 latin_capital_letter_a_with_acute.png
```

Here is the result, which looks OK to me:

[image: PNG, generated from SVG]

My version of ImageMagick is (according to `convert -version`):

```
 Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64 2014-12-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
 Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
 Features: DPC Modules
 Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc \
                       jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr \
                       pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

However, it is not ImageMagick directly and all by itself that does the heavy-lifting of interpreting the SVG. My ImageMagick uses an external delegate to achieve this. How exactly this works can be made visible by adding the `-verbose` setting to the command line:

```
convert -verbose letter_a_with_acute.svg letter_a_with_acute.png

 "/opt/local/bin/inkscape" "/var/tmp/magick-12470O5QRRVap0Ub4" \
     --export-eps="/var/tmp/magick-124705G1EV-reRRrb" --export-dpi="90,90" \
     --export-background="rgb(100%,100%,100%)" --export-background-opacity="1" \
       > "/var/tmp/magick-12470W9feuKm0JHUA" 2>&1

 /var/tmp/magick-12470qEPdaNM3mKYw1 PNG 155x209 155x209+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3.04KB 0.000u 0:00.000
 /var/tmp/magick-124705G1EV-reRRrb PS 155x209 155x209+0+0 16-bit sRGB 3.04KB 0.000u 0:00.000

 letter_a_with_acute.svg=>/var/tmp/magick-124705G1EV-reRRrb PS 155x209 155x209+0+0 16-bit sRGB 3.04KB 0.000u 0:00.000
 letter_a_with_acute.svg=>latin_capital_letter_a_with_acute.png PS 155x209 155x209+0+0 8-bit sRGB 17c 2.93KB 0.000u 0:00.000

 [ghostscript library] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT \
                       -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 \
                      "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 \
                      "-r72x72" -g155x209  "-sOutputFile=/var/tmp/magick-12470qEPdaNM3mKYw%d" \
                      "-f/var/tmp/magick-12470Xt3b3Qubkxx2" \
                      "-f/var/tmp/magick-12470VRcUz0MbmdiC"
```

As you can clearly see, `convert` employs two delegates in two different steps to bring about the conversion:

1. First, it runs an `inkscape` command. This command exports the SVG to EPS.
2. Second, it runs a Ghostscript command. This command converts the EPS from step 1 to the final PNG.
3. In between the above two steps, it runs some other command, probably `identify`, in order to find out the dimensions of the EPS that was produced.

In other words, if you are not able to set up your ImageMagick *delegates* correctly so that they will process SVG files for you, you could always use Inkscape directly on the command line to create the PNG:

```
inkscape                                    \
  --without-gui                             \
  --export-png=out.png                      \
  --export-dpi="90,90"                      \
  --export-background="rgb(100%,100%,100%)" \
  --export-background-opacity="1"           \
    input.svg
```

Looking at the result, `out.png`, it seems like it may be using too much white space around the letter:

```
  identify out.png  
   out.png PNG 744x1052 744x1052+0+0 8-bit sRGB 13.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

This can be rectified by ImageMagick:

```
  convert out.png -trim +repage trimmed.png
```

Check:

```
  identify trimmed.png 
   trimmed.png PNG 193x260 193x260+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 3.53KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: On the server I'm at I have a different version with different delegates. Since I'm on a shared host upgrading is going to be tricky. Thanks for the explanation. $ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP